# Call variable from another script in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, call

I currently have a HTML file that has one script that is declared as follows:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">                         
 $(document).ready(function() {                           
    code.......
    var a = "hello"
});                                             
  </script>
```

I am trying to add another script within the HTML file that will call on this variable "a". Right now, I am doing something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                               
    alert(a);                                                              
</script>
```

But it is not alerting anything. If I replace a with a string like "hello", I do get alerted. Am I calling the variable wrong? I've tried searching for solutions but all of them say you should be able to easily call variables from another script assuming that script is declared and initialized before. Thanks.

Comment: your `alert()` code runs IMMEDIATELY when that `<script>` block is encountered. the other stuff will only run AFTER the entire document has been parsed/set up, so basically you're alerting BEFORE the variable ever has a chance to get defined.

Comment: Is it alerting nothing, or is it not alerting at all?

Comment: Hi Marc, that makes sense. I'll try making a quick fix. It was not alerting at all yak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `a` declaration outside of the function.

E.g.,

```
var a;

$(document).ready(function() {                           
    code.......
    a = "hello"
});
```

And then later on...

```
alert(a);
```

Remember that variables are *function-scoped*, so if you define it inside of a function, it won't be visible outside of the function.

---

*Update based on comments:*

Because you now have a timing issue when trying to interact with the `a` variable, I would recommend introducing an event-bus (or some other mechanism) to coordinate on timing.  Given that you're already using jQuery, you can create a simple bus as follows:

```
var bus = $({});

bus.on('some-event', function() {});
bus.trigger('some-event', ...);
```

This actually lends itself to some better code organization, too, since now you really only need the bus to be global, and you can pass data around in events, rather than a bunch of other random variables.

E.g.,

```
var bus = $({});

$(document).ready(function() {                           
    var a = 'hello';
    bus.trigger('some-event', { a: a });
});
```

And then in your other file:

```
bus.on('some-event', function(e, data) {
    alert(data.a);
});
```

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/pafohetuhi/edit?js,console) (obviously not spread across multiple files, but the same principles apply).

Comment: Hi, so I am able to now call on the variable successfully but the alert is saying that it is undefined so for some reason I guess the variable is not being initialized. Any reason as to why that may be? In my code, I am actually getting data from a file in this .ready() function and am making new variables when parsing the data so I cannot just declare and initialize the variable before the .ready() function.

Comment: This would simply be an order-of-execution problem, from the sounds of it. Basically, you're waiting for the DOM ready event in the first file before you initialize the variable, but you aren't waiting for that in the second file before alerting the variable. You may want to consider reorganizing your code or introducing an event bus of some sort to handle cross-file timing issues.

Comment: Ahhhh yeah that makes sense. I'll make a quick fix and hopefully it'll be fine then. I'll let you know what happens!

Comment: Great. Your edited information worked!!! So if I have multiple variables inside the ready() function, would I have to create a new trigger for each variable then or would I have to create a new var bus for each one? i.e. var bus2, var bus3, ...etc I'm assuming theres no shortcut in where you only need one trigger and can add multiple variables.

Comment: No, you'd want to use just the one event bus (most likely for the entire app, really). Just stuff as much data in there as you want.  You can of course create new events if/when it makes sense, but if you just have a few values that need to be exposed after DOM ready, you can probably just use the single event for initialization.  E.g., `bus.trigger('some-event', { a: 'hello', b: 'world', foo: 'bar' })`, and then you'll have access to `data.a`, `data.b`, and `data.foo` in the `some-event` handler. It's a pretty malleable approach.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: plus 1 for such a great Explanation .. @jmar777

Comment: Quick question, but in my other file when I am running bus.on(), is there anyway I can store the data value in there and then use it elsewhere? For example, doing something like 

    `<script>
       var data;
       bus.on('some-event', function(e, data) {
           data = (data.a);
       });
       alert(data);`
Or is doing something like that not possible at all?

Comment: Well, the issue with that code there is that you don't have access to `data` outside of the `some-event` handler. You can of course pass that value around once you have it in the other file, so you'd probably be better off defining a function that accepts `data`, and you can then invoke that function from the `some-event` handler. That helps insure that you're not running into some of the timing problems that the event-bus is designed to avoid in the first place.

Comment: Generally speaking, you really want to avoid relying on a lot of global variables for passing data around. Not only are they hard to keep track of (and easy to clobber), but they also get really gnarly when you need to wait for various actions to complete before accessing them. Events really provide a nice solution to this problem, and even though they might feel foreign at first, they're ultimately fairly easy to reason about.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code as

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var a="";                        
    $(document).ready(function() {                           
        a = "hello";      
    });                                             
</script>
```

Now you can access the variable `a` as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                               
    alert(a);                                                              
</script>
```

The problem with your code was that, you was declaring the variable `a` inside `$(document).ready()` which made it local to the `ready()`.

Comment: In my code, I am actually getting data from a file in this .ready() function and am making new variables when parsing the data so I cannot just declare and initialize the variable before the .ready() function. Is there anyway I can initialize a variable in one .ready() function and call it in another script?

Comment: No need to do that completley in `ready()`. Instead just declare it outside and initialise it inside as in my edited asnwer.

Comment: I think it was because I was calling that alert before it was getting initialized, but I'll try your edited answer as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you write a inside function block you make it a local variable, you can move variable declaration outside of the function block as other answer say or you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                           
    window.a = "hello";
});
```

and later:

```
alert(a);
```

In both cases you are declaring a as a global variable and that is not recommended.

Comment: Would you recommend creating two separate javascript files and then calling on both of them in my HTML file then?

Comment: Not really, using separate files does not change the scope, variables could be global or local even if they are on separate files. You could define a global object variable and use it as a namespace for your application. `var myApp = {}` outside of any block, then inside of the function block use `myApp.a = 'Hello world'` and on the second script tag `alert(myApp.a)`

Comment: A really interesting article on js namespacing http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/